# Do I need the source code of my webapp for PhoneGap?

Tags: web-applications, progressive-web-apps, phonegap

I have a webapp which I would like to port to the webstore but I dont want to maintain two codebases. Can I just use a Link to package the app in phonegap or di I need to use the sourcecode?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a hosted app. The packeged app will contain the minimum to run the app. The rest is shown inside a browser window. This way you will have only 1 codebase.

You might want to have a look at [PWA Builder](http://www.pwabuilder.com/generator). This will generate a hosted web app for Android, iOS and Windows. This is a great starting point to build from.

You can even use native phone features through Cordova plugins, right from your website. Another great advantage of a hosted app is that you don't have to go though the store certification process every time you update something in your website, because the package does not change.

Answer (score 0):

When I build a Cordova / Phonegap App I detect if the app is running under Cordova, if not remove / hide features for Cordova plugins.

```
if window.cordova....
```

This way these Mutli-Channel sites can be deployed as a site and as an app.